# Does the page number matter?

Tags: publications

Does the page number of scientific publication mean something? For example, are papers of an issue highlighted by placing them in the first pages?

Or they are the page number just randomly assigned?

Comment: I'd speculate that the page number corresponds to the camera-ready date of the article, i.e., lower page numbering of an article means it reached camera-ready status before articles with higher page numberings. You could check whether this holds for a particular issue of a journal that publishes acceptance dates. (Noting that there's some difference between acceptance date and camera-ready date.)

Comment: Of course, when you refer to something in a paper or book, give the exact page number of it.  Do not merely refer to the whole paper or book.  IMPORTANT

Comment: @GEdgar I favour referring to sections (and to a lesser extent chapters) since page numbers may vary in different versions of a document (e.g., a published manuscript and the corresponding technical report, or different editions of a book), whereas sections (and chapters) are less likely to change.

Comment: Also, don't forget that in many cases, page numbers carry over from one issue to another within a volume. So if *Journal 7.1* starts on page 1 and ends at 145, *Journal 7.2* may very well start at 146. Libraries will often bind together several issues making this continuous page numbering more useful. So even if within a given issue ordering were important, the page number itself won't be necessary indicative of anything.

Comment: @GEdgar: "*give the exact page number of it*" Especially if it the reference to something like Zygmund's **Trigonometric Series** treatise and the word or phrase involved is not in the index, something I've encountered many times. Recently, I was looking at many papers on lineability properties, and one of the things I saw over and over again was that Lebesgue in his 1904 book supposedly gave the first example of an everywhere surjective function, but *NO ONE* gave any indication as to where, and I suspect most of the authors never even looked it up. (It's on p. 90 of that 138 page book.)

Comment: Let's randomly assign page numbers to a publication of 1000 pages ... :)

Comment: @GEdgar: Surprisingly, I happened to remember my 13 December 2017 comment AND was able to find it by googling. I thought I'd update my comment with a specific example that I just came across. At the beginning of the 1991 paper [*Removable singularities for analytic functions of Zygmund class*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20489388) by Lord/O'Farrell, reference is made to Zygmund's 2-volume treatise (a total of roughly 750 pages of densely packed text) for "Zygmund class" functions. Of course, Zygmund doesn't use this term and Zygmund's index doesn't help in trying to locate it. **(continued)**

Comment: Worse, there's a typo in Lord/O'Farrell's definition of "Zygmund class" (one of the z+h's in their displayed inequality should be z-h). FYI, Zygmund calls these functions "smooth" and they're introduced on p. 43 of Volume I of his treatise (1959 2nd edition, the edition Lord/O'Farrell cite).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***tl;dr*-**  Page numbers are a hold-over from when journals used to be magazines.  The exact number chosen probably doesn't have much practical significance, but it may relate to when an article was ready for publication ([camera-ready date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera-ready)) or however the editor might choose to lay out the issue (e.g., with related articles closer to each other).

---

Once-upon-a-time, [scientific journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_journal) were basically magazines that collected articles interesting to a specific scholarly community.  Today, libraries still retain some in reference sections and I think that some publishers still actually print them out, but they're mostly funny novelties or historical artifacts.

Anyway, these old-fashion journal volumes would have a table-of-contents that'd refer to page numbers.  Then when the internet came around, they basically stayed the same, except they put copies of articles online, too.  And so, the online copies retain page numbers as a [vestigial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestigiality) artifact: they're not really useful to most folks today, but they're still there anyway for historical reasons.

#### Speculation on what page numbers may've implied

Since page numbers basically reflected order within a printed edition, it'd seem that they likely correlated with how the editors chose to lay out the printed editions.  This may've varied from journal-to-journal.

Possibilities:

1. **Article content.**  Articles may've been laid out such that closely related articles would be consecutive.  In such cases, page numbers would correlate with an article's topic.
2. **Camera-ready date.**  [@user2768 suggested](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100439/does-the-page-number-matter#comment261338_100439) that articles may've been laid out in the order that their content was ready to be amended to the current edition's proof, i.e. the articles' [camera-ready date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera-ready).

Comment: "Once-upon-a-time" is still true today: Journals are printed and archived in libraries. Albeit, this is becoming less common. Regarding speculation on editors putting articles on related topics together, this can be witnessed in journals that group related articles under common headings. I'd speculate that the ordering of those headings doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Kinda curious; do kids today necessarily know about magazines?  It's weird to think that stuff like watching TV for news/weather, or reading a newspaper, were so ubiquitous but rapidly becoming unknown in some demographics.

Comment: About "article content", some journals have explicit parts devoted to specific topics.

Comment: So, you people are saying that the difference between magazine and journal is whether it is printed or not?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience In the above, I was referring to a "_journal_" as an academic journal, which'd be a body of articles.  A "_magazine_" would be a particular form-factor, like a book.  These terms can mean different things in other contexts; for example, a "_book_" can just as readily be an e-book.